# What is the equivalent of Base64.encodeToString(bytes,11) in python?

Tags: python, java, android, base64

I am trying to recreate a java program in python, but I am stuck at this point

```
import android.util.Base64 -> this is the package

Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 11)
```

The python module for encoding with base64 only gets one parameter, which is `bytes`.

apparently, according to [the android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64), the second parameter is supposed to indicate a `flag`, but I can't find any information about the number `11`

What does this mean and how can I implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11 is a combination of flags (or-ed together), specifically:

- [NO_PADDING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#NO_PADDING), which has value `1`
- [NO_WRAP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#NO_WRAP) which has value `2` and
- [URL_SAFE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#CRLF) which has value `8`.

I don't know the exact way to reproduce this in Python, but I believe [`base64.urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) gets you halfway there by implementing the equivalent of `URL_SAFE`. For `NO_PADDING` you could simply trim any trailing padding (i.e. `=` charcters) in the output.